# onclick javascript regex required on the click of a button

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am looking for the regex when I click on the button it should be able to perform "Pay Later" action, currently when this button is clicked it display the values in form of parameter to jmeter along with the post. Where I am able to fetch different id by manually adding through csv data but I need a regex for randomly performing the action

For example

```
<button id="carFlyOutBtn" class="carFlyOutBtn" onclick="javascript:setPayType('0','0',2,1); Analytics.trackEvent('Car Selection','Pay Later',$('#costco_page_name').val());">Pay Later</button>
```

Jmeter Sampler Post
[image: Jmeter Sampler Post]

Post Data in Jmeter
[image: Post Data in Jmeter]

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest : i tried using the regrex for this i work but it did not success the sampler, similar to the post in jmeter. I have added screenshot also for the same. Please check. I need the regrex to retrieve data in this form

Comment: @please dont downvote this one.. i really need an answer. I will provide the required details

Comment: @RichaYadav No matter how hard I try, I am not able to understand your question. Just mention the input string and expected output from that string. we can work on a regex for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at JMeter's [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) which generates random numbers in a given range, for example `${__Random(0,4,)}` expression will give you a random number between 0 and 4 (inclusively) each time the function will be called. So if you configure your HTTP Request sampler like this:

[image: JMeter Random Function Example]

It will generate a random `payType` parameter for each HTTP Request:

[image: JMeter Random Demo]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.